# allow access of global variables in included files from a class method

Tags: php

I have a curious question, I'm importing an existing application into my project.

I have a class that has a method that requires files with functions in them. These functions make us of global variables.

I noticed that these functions cannot share a global variable between them because they are being called from a class method.

I know that if I first declare the global variables then require the files I can the included functions to make use of them. The issue that I have is that these included files with their own functions has 100's of global variable references. It will be extremely time consuming to fish through all the files and redeclare the global variables.

Is there a more direct approach of doing this?

example would be

```
//class file
class run
{
    public function install()
    {
        require_once('file.php);
    }
}

//file.php
require('some/other/file.php);
function checks() {
   global $someVar;
   $somVar->test();
}
```

this will obviously throw an error like cannot access test() to non-object something something, unless I declare $someVar within the `run::install()`

Comment: That's why you should (almost) never use global variables

Comment: yup, but i'm importing an existing application that makes use of them.

Comment: Global state is really really bad!  You should avoid it, pass the variables your method needs in as arguments instead (I see you mentioned you're trying to integrate new code into a legacy app, but your new code can use arguments and not resort to global).

Comment: i'm loading up wordpress, wordpress has terrible code! i can't seem to load it within a function

Answer (score 0):

Just do your require's of Wordpress files at the global level (before anything else, that is) instead of from within your methods. In your example all you need is being able to access the `checks()` function. Of course, cross fingers that there is no name clash...

Comment: tried every which way and i won't work unless i declare wordpress's global variables locally before requiring any of its files.